# Combine two Lambda expressions using result of first Lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I was wondering if it's possible to combine these two statements into one.

```
Tbl_OrderFeeItem orderFee = adj.Tbl_Order.Tbl_OrderFeeItem.Single(x =>
                        x.OrderId == adj.OrderId
                        && x.FeeTypeId == adj.FeeTypeId);


int querySource = orderFee.Tbl_FeeCheck
                 .Single(x => x.OrderFeeItemId == formFee.OrderFeeItemId)
                 .Tbl_PostPaymentOrderQuery
                 .PostPaymentOrderQueryTypeId;
```

What I'm trying to do is something like this...

```
int querySource = adj.Tbl_Order.Tbl_OrderFeeItem.Single(x =>
                  x.OrderId == adj.OrderId && x.FeeTypeId == adj.FeeTypeId)
                  .Tbl_FeeCheck.Single('use the id from the result of Tbl_OrderFeeItem.Single() call')
                  .Tbl_PostPaymentOrderQuery.PostPaymentOrderQueryTypeId;
```

I hope that made sense, I'm trying to use the id from the first query in the second but have it as one complete statement instead of two separate ones.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to provide an accurate answer without any of the constructs present in your program, but by surrounding the original query with brackets it should allow you to perform the second query on the result of the first without using two seperate statements:

```
((Tbl_OrderFeeItem)adj.Tbl_Order.Tbl_OrderFeeItem.Single(x =>
                  x.OrderId == adj.OrderId
                  && x.FeeTypeId == adj.FeeTypeId))
              .Tbl_FeeCheck
              .Single(x => x.OrderFeeItemId == formFee.OrderFeeItemId)
              .Tbl_PostPaymentOrderQuery
              .PostPaymentOrderQueryTypeId;
```